# android - make a spinner or not pprogrammatically

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

This is a spinner defined in the xml layout below.

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am using the spinner in the activity class as shown below

```
void spinner(){
        spMem=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapterMem=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,listItemsMem);
        spMem.setAdapter(adapterMem);
        spMem.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        ........................
```

considering that when the above method is called, how can I disabled it from appearing from a users sight.

Comment: what are you asking exactly?. hide spinner or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every view has a `setVisibility()` method. you can use it to set a view's appearance to `INVISIBLE`, `GONE` and `VISIBLE`.